# do javascript switch statement case allows to use an expression

Tags: javascript, expression, switch-statement, case

if yes, why this code doesn't alert anything?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   switch ("hello world") {
      case "hello" + " world": 
        alert("Greeting was found.");
        break;
    case "goodbye": 
        alert("Closing was found.");
        break;
    default: 
        alert("Unexpected message was found.");
}
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the point of this switch, anyway? Why compare constants against other constants?

Comment: works as expected for me, ff3.6

Comment: Works for me in Chrome, Firefox, and IE 8; which browser  are you using?

Comment: i just want to test wheter the expression used to compare with the argument in the switch statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/BJLCb/) in...

- Firefox 3.6
- Chrome 10

With a switch, you generally compare it to constants. The way you are using it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it accepts [expressions](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11). [From the specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12.11):

> *CaseClause* :
>   case *Expression* : *StatementList*<sub>opt</sub>

And as the others say, it seems to work for them. Probably you have another error in your real code.